# How to make increment if same name occurs using triggers?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a table:

```
id
name
amount
```

If the same `name` was inserted, then `amount` should be incremented.
Else, insert with 0 amount.

How to create a trigger with a given condition?

Comment: Read this.. [Why should i provide an mcve for what seems to me to be a very simple sql query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You should change the design of your application and not implement  such business logics in a Trigger. If you want to see an aggregated form of data from the table, create and use a VIEW instead.

Comment: this question was on my assessment work, I didn't know  how to write such a query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't really be doing that. `AMOUNT` column effectively counts number of `NAME` appearances in that table. You can always count it, can't you? So, what's the purpose of doing that?

If you want to know which *name* was inserted prior (or after) some other *name* (equal to the previous one), sort them by `ID` (if it is incremental, such as an identity column or if it gets its value from a sequence).

If `ID` isn't incremental, add `DATE_INSERTED` column (and sort by it; or apply `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function which orders values by `DATE_INSERTED`).

Also, what happens if you *delete* one of those duplicate names? Will you retroactively decrement `AMOUNT` column for all previous instances of that `NAME`?

---

But, if you insist, here's one option. As you can't just *select* from a table you're inserting into (because of the mutating table error), I'm using a compound trigger. The part of "insert amount 0" is done by setting the column's default value (you don't need any code for that).

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (id     number primary key,
  3     name   varchar2(20),
  4     amount number default 0);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace trigger trg_ai_test
  2    for insert on test
  3    compound trigger
  4
  5    type test_rt is record (id test.id%type,
  6                            name test.name%type);
  7    type rli_t is table of test_rt index by pls_integer;
  8    g_rli rli_t;
  9
 10  after each row is
 11  begin
 12    g_rli(g_rli.count + 1).id := :new.id;
 13    g_rli(g_rli.count).name := :new.name;
 14  end after each row;
 15
 16  after statement is
 17    l_cnt number;
 18  begin
 19    for i in 1 .. g_rli.count loop
 20      dbms_output.put_Line('x');
 21      dbms_output.put_line(i ||' '|| g_rli(i).id ||' '||g_rli(i).name);
 22      select count(*) into l_cnt
 23        from test
 24        where name = g_rli(i).name;
 25
 26      update test set
 27        amount = l_cnt
 28        where id = g_rli(i).id;
 29    end loop;
 30
 31  end after statement;
 32  end trg_ai_test;
 33  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into test (id, name) values (1, 'little');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test (id, name) values (2, 'foot');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test (id, name) values (3, 'little');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into test (id, name) values (9, 'little');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME                     AMOUNT
---------- -------------------- ----------
         1 little                        1
         2 foot                          1
         3 little                        2
         9 little                        3

SQL>
```

Or, a simpler solution (described above), without using that much code:

```
SQL> select id, name,
  2    row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as amount
  3  from test;

        ID NAME                     AMOUNT
---------- -------------------- ----------
         2 foot                          1
         1 little                        1
         3 little                        2
         9 little                        3

SQL>
```

Comment: By the way, question was asked in assesment task,  and claimed as: **Create a trigger that react only on insertion statements for the table employee. And assign a number+1 to the samename according to already existing number of
employees in database with same name.**

Comment: This works only in a single-user environment. Assume one sessions inserts `'little'` but without commit. Then another sessions also enters `'little'`. Unless the first insert is commited the data would be wrong. As Littlefoot stated properly: **You shouldn't really be doing that.**